# Query return NULL when using STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

i have two questions, using below query:

1. this query is for select list purpose. I want to display period1 as the text while period2 as the option value. Is this a good practice? Any vulnerability where user can exploit the select list?
2. Why the query return NULL for period2?

   ```
   select distinct 
          STR_TO_DATE(period, '%Y-%m-%d') as period1,
          STR_TO_DATE(period, '%Y%m%d') as period2 
   from table
   ```

Comment: You dont provide enough information. If you worried for vulnerability use parametrized query. Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting `NULL` lies in the definition of `STR_TO_DATE`:

> If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal,
>   STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning. The server scans
>   str attempting to match format to it.

Given that definiton, it is clear that the same `period`-string as input cannot match two different formats; hence, one of the two `STR_TO_DATE`-calls will give an invalid date, i.e. `NULL`.

I suppose, however, that `period` is actually a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) datatype, and you mean `DATE_FORMAT`, not `STR_TO_DATE`, right? Assuming this, the following query should work:

```sql
select DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y-%m-%d') as period1,DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y%m%d') as period2  from test
```

When using this scheme...

```sql
create table test (
  period date
);
insert into test (period) values ("2016-12-01");
```

it yields the following result:

```sql
period1    | period2
2016-12-01 | 20161201
```

Comment: OMG... I've been using STR_TO_DATE for the whole project. I thought the STR_TO_DATE function is to convert the datetime field to specific format we want?! ....